# Obtaining values for environmental variables using PyOpengl

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

Simple query. I am trying to get access to the `GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE` value using pyOpengl using the following:

```py
size= glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE)
```

But I get the following error

```
File c:\Python\Miniconda3\envs\opengl\Lib\site-packages\OpenGL\error.py:230, in _ErrorChecker.glCheckError(self, result, baseOperation, cArguments, *args)
    228 err = self._currentChecker()
    229 if err != self._noErrorResult:
--> 230     raise self._errorClass(
    231         err,
    232         result,
    233         cArguments = cArguments,
    234         baseOperation = baseOperation,
    235     )
    236 return result

GLError: GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'invalid operation',
    baseOperation = glGetIntegerv,
    pyArgs = (
        GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE,
        ,
    ),
    cArgs = (
        GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE,
        array([0], dtype=int32),
    ),
    cArguments = (
        GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE,
        array([0], dtype=int32),
    )
)
```

What is the correct way of retrieving this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'invalid operation' indicates that you are trying to retrieve the parameter before the [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) has been created. Usually, the OpenGL Context is created along with the OpenGL window. You cannot use any OpenGL API function until this is done.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. The reason why I was not getting any answer was because I was asking this information without initializing a context (i.e. a window) in opengl. I thought that one could ask this from the system at anytime but apparently this is not true.

Comment: So what is the difference between your answer and my answer?

Comment: @Rabbid76 You are absolutely right! There is no difference. I originally had not made the connection between 'context' and 'window'. I was running my code in a python notebook and had not run the creation of the window before.